# Getting not secure warning for www domain

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, lets-encrypt

I installed lets encrypt using certbot when I go to the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) I get this site is not secure error

```
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: example.com
    Domains: example.com
    Expiry Date: 2023-05-25 15:01:00+00:00 (VALID: 70 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: www.example.com
    Domains: www.example.com
    Expiry Date: 2023-06-13 16:14:03+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
```

Apache SSL conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public_html/public
SSLEngine                on
<Directory /var/www/example/public_html/public>
         Options +FollowSymLinks
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
SSLCertificateFile       /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include  /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I make it work for www domain also?

Comment: Why don't you use a LetsEncrypt certificate which contains both domains?

Comment: @A.B sorry it should be 2.4

Answer (score 1):

You need to get one certificate with correct Subject Alternate Name.

You can delete the `www.example.com` and `example.com` certificates, and [request a new for `example.com` *and* `wwww.example.com`](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/host-multiple-domains-with-a-single-certificate/20917).

Comment: How can I delete only www certificate? because If I delete both of them, site will be broken. Can I first delete the www cert. and then convert example.com to wildcard?

Comment: You don't need wildcard. You need a cert with two names. `certbot delete --certname www.example.com` should do the trick. And yes; the site *will* be broken for some seconds when you switch over anyway.